# 0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: macos, curl

I'm trying to install pip with curl on macOS on 10.14.3.

This command `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` has the following output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0        0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0 curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

I tried to ping `bootstrap.pypa.io` and the server responded.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`curl` is preferable but not needed here. If `ping` can access the server but `curl` can't, simply [navigate to the file](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and copy-paste its content into a locally created `get-pip.py`, and continue the installation.