# Can't install pip on macos using curl

Tags: python, macos, pip

Can't install pip on my macOS laptop so I searched on how to install it and told me to use this

> `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

typed it into the terminal and got an error

```
raphael@Raphaels-MBP ~ % curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py 

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   
  0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

This happened yesterday and just thought that it might work today. But it still doesn't.

Tried other solutions from:

[How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

[I can't install PIP on MacOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126234/i-cant-install-pip-on-macos-sierra)

Still didn't work

Comment: Why are you installing `pip` at all?  Pip should have come along with Python when you installed it.  Versions of `pip` are usually intimately tied to their accompanying Python version.  How did you install your Python(s)?  Is `pip` not there for each of them?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to include that I have also installed python from the official website since it said that it would have pip installed with it. But when I try to type ```pip``` an error would appear ```zsh: command not found: pip```

Comment: Have you tried `pip3` instead? I think some distributions of Python 3.X use this name only.  If you want a `pip` to go with it, just go into the directory that contains `pip3` and do `sudo ln -s pip3 pip`.  I believe I did that for each of my recent Python 3.X installs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112387/0curl-7-couldnt-connect-to-server

Comment: Thanks @Steve! I think I'll be using pip3 instead of pip